# Double integral over the region enclosed by 4 curves.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm a bit stuck on a problem that involves trying to integrate the area between 4 curves.

**Problem:**

$\int \int_D x^2+y^2 dxdy$

Where D is the region enclosed by the curves $xy =2, xy=7, y= 2x^2$ and $y=5x^2$.

For this, I set $u=y/x^2$, $v=xy$ and then work through the problem. In the end, I find that I can't fully rewrite the end integral in terms of $u$ and $v$, so am likely making a mistake somewhere.

Any help in solving this would be much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $u=y/x^2$, $v=xy$, we first need to write $x^2+y^2$. Solving for $y$ on both equalities we obtain $x^2u=v/x$, so $x^3=v/u$. Then $x^2=(v/u)^{2/3}$. Squaring the second equality, $v^2=x^2y^2$, so $y/u=v^2/y^2$, or $y^3=v^2/u$. Then
$$
x^2+y^2=\left(\frac{v}{u}\right)^{2/3}+\left(\frac{v^2}{u}\right)^{2/3}.
$$
The Jacobian is 
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
x_u&y_u\\ x_v&y_v
\end{vmatrix}
=\begin{vmatrix}
-\dfrac13\,\dfrac{v^{1/3}}{u^{4/3}}&-\dfrac13\,\dfrac{v^{2/3}}{u^{4/3}}\\
\dfrac13\,\dfrac{v^{-2/3}}{u^{1/3}}&\dfrac23\,\dfrac{v^{-1/3}}{u^{1/3}}
\end{vmatrix}
=-\dfrac19\left(\frac{2}{u^{5/3}} -\frac{v^{4/3}}{u^{5/3}}\right)
$$
since $x=(v/u)^{1/3}$, $y=(v^2/u)^{1/3}$. Now you can form the integral
$$
-\frac19\int_2^7\int_2^5\left(\left(\frac{v}{u}\right)^{2/3}+\left(\frac{v^2}{u}\right)^{2/3}\right)\,\left(\frac{2}{u^{5/3}} -\frac{v^{4/3}}{u^{5/3}}\right)\,dv\,du.
$$
This is trivial after distributing.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't expect the solution to be that complicated. Would you recommend changing what $u$ and $v$ are set to (to achieve a cleaner solution)?

Comment: It is not surprising that the solution looks nasty. In the original integral the roles of $x$ and $y$ are symmetric, while $u$ and $v$ are not symmetric (because the two pairs of curves that limit your region are of a different kind). I'm not sure what you mean by "changing what $u$ and $v$ are".

Comment: On another note, welcome to Math SE. I don't mind if you do it or not for my answer, but usually in this site if you find something useful/interesting the suggestion is that you upvote it using the up arrow. The voting system is an essential part of the SE network.